# Find partial sum of this series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2n+3}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{1}^{\infty } \frac{2n+3}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$

How to find partial sum, sum and prove convergence by definition? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What did you try to prove the convergence for example?

Comment: get Wolfie to do it for you ... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+(2n%2B3)%2F(n(n%2B1)(n%2B2)(n%2B3))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{2n+3}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$

Resolve it into partial fractions,

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}]$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: use that $$\frac{2n+3}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=-1/2\, \left( n+1 \right) ^{-1}-1/2\, \left( n+2 \right) ^{-1}+1/2\,
 \left( n+3 \right) ^{-1}+1/2\,{n}^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\;\;\cfrac{2n+3}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\cfrac{1}{n(n+2)} - \cfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+3)}$